# How to sort posts by the average of comment meta values

Tags: comments, loop, comment-meta, meta-value

Here's the situation-

I've customized the comment submission whereby users can provide a rating, and this gets stored as a meta value in the commentmeta table.  I can query to return the average value and display in the post. No problem so far.

What I want to do now is sort posts by this average rating.

My code to get the average rating is:

```
function average_rating() {
global $wpdb;
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$ratings = $wpdb->get_results("

    SELECT $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_value
    FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->comments on $wpdb->comments.comment_id=$wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id
    WHERE $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_key='rating' 
    AND $wpdb->comments.comment_post_id=$post_id 
    AND $wpdb->comments.comment_approved =1

    ");
$counter = 0;
$average_rating = 0;    
if ($ratings) {
    foreach ($ratings as $rating) {
        $average_rating = $average_rating + $rating->meta_value;
        $counter++;
    } 
    //round the average to the nearast 1/2 point
    return (round(($average_rating/$counter)*2,0)/2);  
} else {
    //no ratings
    return 'no rating';
}
}
```

I'm thinking I need to start storing the average value as a post meta field otherwise I'd have to loop through queries within queries with multiple joins, which seems to be a really bad idea.  I'm hoping someone with a fresh set of eyes can help me think through architecting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done exactly something similar. First, use `get_comment_meta` for getting the per comment rating, you don't need the SQL for it. Then get the average rating (addition of individual comment ratings on a single post / number of comments on this post). Then store this average value as post meta for this post. Use `WP_Query` custom fields parameters for ordering these posts.

Comment: that's where I'm getting a bit stuck - how to store the avg value as post meta. since this value changes as more comments are added - perhaps the approving the comment would be the appropriate trigger?

Comment: Exactly. Use `comment_unapproved_to_approved` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_%28old_status%29_to_%28new_status%29) action hook to update the final average when the comment is approved (and vice versa as `comment_approved_to_unapproved`). You'll also have to keep a track when the comment is deleted or trashed (use `trashed_comment` or `deleted_comment`), to subtract that comment's rating from the addition and recalculate the score.

Comment: I update the sum of all ratings as post meta, every time a comment is approved/unapproved/trashed/untrashed/deleted using the above hooks. Also store the comment count as another post meta value. Then get these two wherever I want to use them, calculate the average there.

Comment: cool. I think that will work.

Comment: It will my friend, it definitely will. If stuck, feel free to ask me!

Comment: ok, circling back on this. I've got a function that pulls all approved comments for a post, calculated the average, and updates the post meta field accordingly.  it works fine when hooked to `comment_unapproved_to_approved` & `comment_approved_to_unapproved`, but doesn't appear to work when hooked to `trashed_comment`.  Perhaps I'm missing something?